# Refreshing the Problems View in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Sometimes I have "**unresolved inclusions**" in my C++ projects. Rebuilding the index in the project removes the markers from the source code, but the the `Problems View` still lists them as if they had not been resolved.

The only way to get them to go away from the `Problems View` is to click on them, which opens the corresponding file with the `#include` directive, and makes Eclipse realize that they had been resolved (Eclipse then removes all the inclusion problems associated with the file).

Is there any way to ask Eclipse to refresh the `Problems View` after rebuilding the index? I have tried  <kbd>F5</kbd> and  <kbd>Ctrl-a F5</kbd> with no luck.

Comment: What kind of project is it? What kinds of files have these errors?

Comment: Have you disabled Project > Build Automatically?

Answer (score 1):

With CDT you likely have to recompile the source code to get rid of the warnings/error markers.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to the problems view at all. The problems view only *displays* the warnings/errors calculated by *other* plugins and is always current. So if this happens with CDT projects, the problem must be searched in the settings of your CDT installation or in the CDT project properties.